# How to display a column in database as a flash message in flasks login

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

Hello i have a verification login system that checks user against a database and send a mail and sms to the verified user and displays a flash welcome message at the bottom of the login page. But i want it to display the flash welcome message together with the name of the verified user. e.g flash ("welcome" "" +name). How can i do it? my code below.

```
def validate3(username, password):
con = sqlite3.connect('static/Users.db')
completion = False
with con:
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Nbc")
            rows = cur.fetchall()
            for row in rows:
                dbUser = row[0]
                dbPass = row[1]
                dbName = row[2]                    
                dbEmail = row[3]
                dbMessage = row[4]
                if dbPass==password:
                    completion=(dbUser, username)
                    #sending email
                    '''fromaddr = "xxxxxxxxx"
                    toaddr = dbEmail                        
                    message = MIMEMultipart()
                    message['From'] = fromaddr
                    message['To'] = toaddr
                    message['Subject'] = dbName
                    body = dbMessage
                    message.attach(MIMEText(body,'plain'))
                    password = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
                    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')                        
                    server.starttls()                        
                    server.login(fromaddr, password)
                    text = message.as_string()
                    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr.split(","), text)
                    server.quit()'''
return completion  



@app.route('/nbc', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def nbc():

error = None
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.form['username']
    password = request.form['password']
    complete = validate3(username, password)
    if complete ==False:
        flash ( 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.')
        return redirect(url_for('nbc'))
    else:
        flash ("Welcome" ""+Name)
        return redirect(url_for('nbc'))
return render_template('nbc.html', error=error)
```

Html template below.

```
 <html lang="en">

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/event.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<form action="/nbc" method="POST">
    <div class="login">
        <div class="login-screen">
            <div class="app-title">
                <h1>Login</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="login-form">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <input type="text" class="login-field" placeholder="username" name="username" value="{{ request.form.username }}">
                    <label class="login-field-icon fui-user" for="login-name"></label>
                </div>

                <div class="control-group">
                    <input type="password" class="login-field" placeholder="password" name="password" value="{{ request.form.password }}">
                    <label class="login-field-icon fui-lock" for="login-pass"></label>
                </div>

                <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block">
                <br>
                <div id="navbar" class="app-titl">
                    <a class="nav navbar-nav"></a>
                    <li class="active"><a href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Home</a></li>
                    <a href="{{ url_for('index') }}"></a>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
{% extends "layout.html" %} {% block body %} {% if error %}
<p class=error><strong>Error:</strong> {{ error }} {% endif %} {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add something like the following to your template, to catch and display any flash message.

```
<div class="flashwrapper">
  {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=True) %}
    {% if messages %}
       {% for category, message in messages %}
          <div id=flashwrapper class="alert alert-{{ category }} alert-dismissible" role="alert">{{ message }}
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close" onClick="close('flashwrapper')">
          </div>
       {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endwith %}
</div>
```

Edit: put something like this in your app file in the right place. I'm not sure where to get the username variable in your code, so you might have to work on that a bit.

```
from flask import flash

flash("Hello {username}. You are most welcome!".format(username), 'success')
```

Comment: Thank you @gittert i added that, but the response i am getting is that name is not defined

Comment: please provide complete error message log (run in debug mode)

Comment: see edit, not sure if you have the flash code in your py file already?

Comment: Thank you @gilbert. It worked, it displayed the welcome message plus the username. I tried to call another column from my database which i want it to display with the welcome message, but i get error code:                               flash ("Welcome {}.".format(Name))
NameError: name 'dbName' is not defined
Name is a column in my database.

Comment: I would suggest return the name of the user in the validation code. false if username/password don't match, and if true, return username. Besides that, mayby have a look at flask-login or flask-security, which makes this a bit easier.